# Behavior of permutations of exponentiation using only $i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

On a lark, I tried enumerating all possible ways of exponentiating $i$ with itself. That is, to generate a list that begins $$\{i,i^i,i^{i^i},{(i^i)}^i,i^{i^{i^i}},i^{{(i^i)}^i},\dots\}$$

...and so forth. I generated every such combination up through ten $i$'s, as Mathematica seemed to be having precision problems around that point.

Assuming it's not a precision error artifact, you start to suddenly see very large values when you hit 10; most of the values were small, a few reached into the tens or hundreds, and one value had real and imaginary parts around $10^{34}$. Specifically, this expression (and three others) apparently correspond to that large value:

$$i^{i^{\left(\left(i^{i^{\left(i^{i^i}\right)^i}}\right)^i\right)^i}}$$

What I found more interesting was what it looks like when you scatter plot all the values near the origin.

[image: scatter plot]

I can't say I'm surprised to see part of a circle taking shape, but it looks like there are at least a couple of other significant curves here. This is not at all in my wheelhouse, and I was wondering if someone knows and could explain why the other curves appear (and if one were to continue doing this, would more and more of them show up?), or point me to an appropriate resource online.